# CoCreateInstance hangs in single-threaded exe COM client

Tags: c++, com

I'm learning the basics of COM. Right now I'm writing out-of-process server.
I wrote pretty basic server app, dll/stub and client app.

If I register server and create an instance of an object using CoCreateInstance in-process, it works:

**SERVER/CLIENT:**

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    IClassFactory *factory = new ISimpleServerFactory();
    DWORD classToken;

    ::CoInitialize(NULL);
    CoRegisterClassObject(
        IID_ISimpleServer, 
        factory, 
        CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, 
        REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE, 
        &classToken);

    ISimpleServer *pISimpleServer = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_CSimpleServer, 
        NULL, 
        CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, 
        IID_ISimpleServer,
        (void **)&pISimpleServer);           //<===========SUCCESS

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        printf("Instantiation successful\n");

    if(pISimpleServer != NULL)
        pISimpleServer->Release();

    std::cin.ignore();
    CoRevokeClassObject(classToken);
    ::CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Now I try splitting it into separate apps:

**SERVER:**

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    IClassFactory *factory = new ISimpleServerFactory();
    DWORD classToken;

    ::CoInitialize(NULL);
    CoRegisterClassObject(
        IID_ISimpleServer, 
        factory, 
        CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, 
        REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE, 
        &classToken);

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        printf("Instantiation successful\n");

    if(pISimpleServer != NULL)
        pISimpleServer->Release();

    std::cin.ignore();
    CoRevokeClassObject(classToken);
    ::CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

**CLIENT:**

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    SimpleServer::ISimpleServer *pISimpleServer = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_CSimpleServer, 
        NULL, 
        CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, 
        IID_ISimpleServer,
        (void **)&pISimpleServer);       // HERE IT HANGS

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        //*****SMTH***
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Failed to load COM object (server not loaded?)\n");
    }

    if(pISimpleServer != NULL)
        pISimpleServer->Release();

    CoUninitialize();

    std::cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

And client hangs on run.
If server is not launched, client types "Failed to load COM object (server not loaded?)", so I suppose it's not a problem of server registration.

But what could it be then?

Comment: Your server is not pumping messages.

Comment: And what does it mean?

Comment: A thread running in a single-threaded apartment (which is what you joined when you called `::CoInitialize(NULL)`) must never block, but must instead run a message pump - that is, call `GetMessage` and `DispatchMessage` (at least) in a loop.  Incoming cross-apartment COM calls are sent to an STA thread in the form of window messages, which said thread must retrieve and process.

Comment: There needs to be a way for the server to know that a client is connecting. Your call to `cin.ignore()` prevents the server from receiving events since it is busy reading from `cin`. COM is not magic fairy dust. In order to process COM events, you need to give a way for COM to get control of your thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so, like Raymond pointed, my server is not pumping messages. I added

```
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0) > 0) 
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
    if(_kbhit())
        break;
}
```

into server body and it got better :)